# CAML query in getLIstItems method returns no rows of items

Tags: web-services, soap, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-list

I am invoking Sharepoint's List Web services and using the getListItems() method. In particular, I am keen on specifying a CAML query because I really want it to just retrieve one item that I am specifically interested in. This I am doing by specifying a query in my XML string, in varying degrees of combinations, either by specifying the EncodedAbsUrl, the LinkFileName, the URL or the FileRef, with most results returning 0. 
 The XML query looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">    <S:Body><GetListItems xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/"><listName>{5cbc4407-3851-4e00-964a-bb7e9b430f9f}</listName>    <viewName></viewName>    <rowLimit>1000</rowLimit>    <webID></webID>

**<query><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name = "FileRef"/><Value Type = "Text">"/Shared%20Documents/Ashish/Word_feb27.doc"</Value></Eq></Where></Query></query>**

<viewFields><ViewFields><FieldRef Name="FSObjType"/><FieldRef Name="LinkFilename"/><FieldRef Name="UniqueId"/><FieldRef Name="FileRef"/><FieldRef Name="FileRef"/><FieldRef Name="EncodedAbsUrl"/><FieldRef Name="FileSizeDisplay"/><FieldRef Name="_UIVersionString"/><FieldRef Name="_owshiddenversion"/></ViewFields></viewFields></GetListItems>    </S:Body></S:Envelope>
```

Without the  tags this Soap request does infact work, and it retrieves all the items that area available in the List. The frustration begins when i specify the query tag. In particular the Following combinations have been attempted by me

**FieldRef.name = {LinkFileName, EncodedAbsUrl, URL,FileRef} and Value.type = {Text, URL}**

Either they yield results with no 0 fields in it or they return internal errors. I figure, this is a syntactical issue and would rather shoot this question to you guys who have probably dunnit in the past to see where I am possibly messing it up.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [CAML Query Builder](http://www.u2u.be/Tools/wincamlquerybuilder/CamlQueryBuilder.aspx) and Fiddler. Query builder can connect SP using Web services and you can build the query with that. After you got your expected results, capture the Web service request with Fiddler and use it :)

BTW: Have you considered using Sharepoint Client Object model? You do not have to worry about SOAP messages.

Comment: legacy code :( . CAML Query Builder seemed painful on first look. Did a work around, what is Fiddler for ?

Comment: You can use Fiddler to monitor WS (HTTP) traffic between CAML Query Builder and Sharepoint. There, you can find SOAP message with less effort (compared to running your code again and again (and again :))

Comment: Agreed.. CAML Builder interface is not the best however you get used to it in time..

Answer (score -1):

Remove the `<query><Query>` tags.

Comment: how does that even help? it's the correct syntax, without them Sharepoint will yield a internal server error coz of malformed request packet

Comment: Ok Sorry than i dnt have any idea.